# sharedptr C++(падает программа)

Tags: c++, memory, smart-pointer

Здравствуйте, использую в программе std::shared_ptr и программа начинает себя вести по странному. У меня программа БД для школы и вот при добавлении к примеру нового ученика она может, как корректно отработать так и упасть. Вот листинг добавления ученика:

#### Модель ученика staff.h / staff.cpp

```
class Pupil : public Models
{
private:
     QString name;
     QString dateOfBirth;
     QString phoneNumber;
     QString personalData;
     QString address;
     QString hisClass;
     Pupil(QString &name, QString &dateOfBirth, QString &phoneNumber,
           QString &personalData, QString &address, QString &hisClass);
public:
    class Builder {
        QString name;
        QString dateOfBirth;
        QString phoneNumber;
        QString personalData;
        QString address;
        QString hisClass;
    public:
        Builder& setName(QString name);
        // Setters ...
        Pupil* build();
    };
    QString getPhoneNumber() const;
    // Getters ...
};

...

// Здесь происходит выделение через умный указатель
Pupil *Pupil::Builder::build()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Pupil> newPupil(new Pupil(name, dateOfBirth, phoneNumber, personalData, address, hisClass));
    return newPupil.get();
}

...
```

#### Форма для работы с учениками pupils_form.h. / pupils_form.сзз

```
...

void PupilsForm::clickedBtnAddPupil()
{
    AddPupilDialog addPupilDialog;
    if(addPupilDialog.exec() == QDialog::Accepted)
    {
        Pupil *pupil = addPupilDialog.getData();
        pupilsModel->addItem(pupil);
    }
}   

...
```

#### Диалог для добавления ученика add_pupil_dialog.h / add_pupil_dialog.cpp

```
...

Pupil *AddPupilDialog::getData()
{
     Pupil *pupil = Pupil::Builder()
           .setName(ui->edtName->text())
           .setNumber(ui->edtPhoneNumber->text())
           .setAddress(ui->edtAddress->text())
           .setDateOfBirth(ui->edtDateOfBirth->text())
           .setPersonalData(ui->edtPersonalData->text())
           .setHisClass(ui->cbxClass->currentText())
           .build();
    return pupil;
}

...
```

#### Класс для работы с моделью ученика pupils_model.h / pupils_model.cpp

```
...    

void PupilsModel::addItem(Models *item)
{
    Pupil *pupil = (Pupil*)item;

    //Prepare for execute the query
    QMap<QString, QString> prepareQuery;
    prepareQuery.insert(":name", pupil->getName());
    prepareQuery.insert(":number", pupil->getPhoneNumber());
    prepareQuery.insert(":address", pupil->getAddress());
    prepareQuery.insert(":personalData", pupil->getPersonalData());
    prepareQuery.insert(":dateOfBirth", pupil->getDateOfBirth());
    prepareQuery.insert(":class", pupil->getHisClass());

    // Здесь программа не падает, выдает корректное ФИО ученика
    qDebug() << pupil->getName();

    //Executing the query
    QString query = "INSERT INTO pupils(name, data_birth, person_data, number, address, id_class)"
                "VALUES(:name, :dateOfBirth, :personalData, :number, :address, "
                "(SELECT c.id FROM classses c WHERE c.name = :class))";
    dataBase->execInsert(query, prepareQuery);
 }

 ...
```

#### Класс для работы с БД database.h / database.cpp

```
void DataBase::execInsert(QString &stringQuery, QMap<QString, QString> &prepareQuery)
{
    QSqlQuery query;
    query.prepare(stringQuery);
    for(auto it = prepareQuery.begin(); it != prepareQuery.end(); it++)
    {
        query.bindValue(it.key(), it.value());
    }

    // А вот здесь как раз таки она иногда и падает с map не читаются данные
    qDebug() << prepareQuery.first();

    query.exec();
    checkSuccessRequest(query);
}
```

Работает это так... Форма учеников у нее обработчик по нажатию на кнопку добавить, которые открывает диалог добавления ученика. В диалоге формируется модель ученика и если диалог успешно сработан, то данные возвращаются к форме и передаются классу для работы с моделью ученика. Там обрабатывается bind-ится поля для запросы и передаются в класс для работы с базой данных. Я вот одного только понять не могу почему иногда работает все нормально, а иногда падает, я бы понял, если бы все время падало, но... Может кто-нибудь поможет или подскажет из-за чего это,уже голову всю изломал.

Answer (score 2):

Не буду копаться и ковыряться везде, скажу только об этом:

```
// Здесь происходит выделение через умный указатель
Pupil *Pupil::Builder::build()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Pupil> newPupil(new Pupil(name, dateOfBirth, phoneNumber, 
                                              personalData, address, hisClass));
    return newPupil.get();
}
```

Итак, создаем локальный `shared_ptr` (зачем?), который на выходе из функции удаляет переданный ему объект в динамической памяти и освобождает память. Так что возвращается указатель на уже освобожденную память. Чистой воды UB.

Уж лучше б вы просто писали

```
Pupil *Pupil::Builder::build()
{
    return new Pupil(name, dateOfBirth, phoneNumber, 
                     personalData, address, hisClass));
}
```

или

```
std::shared_ptr<Pupil> Pupil::Builder::build()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Pupil> newPupil(new Pupil(name, dateOfBirth, phoneNumber, 
                                              personalData, address, hisClass));
    return newPupil;
}
```

Дальше просто не смотрел, этого уже вполне достаточно...

Comment: У меня так и было, но почитал статью на хабре, в которой говорилось о том, что стоит избегать максимально new и delete. Да и плюс ее же придется освобождать аж в диалоге, после передачи данных в Map.

Comment: Понимаете, да, молотком удобнее забивать гвоздь, чем кирпичом. Но бить-то молотком надо по гвоздю, а не по пальцам, простите уж за такую аналогию! `shared_ptr` хранит объект, и освобождает сам - но когда исчезает последний экземпляр! У вас он исчезает сразу при выходе из функции...

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, я понял, но скажите тогда какой из ваших двух вариантов будет лучше? Просто привык писать на Java так как бы не понятных оберток на подобии умных указателей, которые будут возвращаться из ф-ии и передаваться дальше. В С++ такими методами пользуются?

Comment: Зависит от того, что именно вы хотите. Если вы уже работали с просто указателями и код был нормальный - то менять просто ради того, чтоб было "как умные люди советуют" - не вижу смысла. Опять же, где именно и как именно вы будете использовать этот объект. Он реально должен быть "един в нескольких лицах" или владеть им должен только один владелец (тогда лучше использовать `unique_ptr`)? Понимаете, не существует панацеи, или того, что американцы называют "серебряной пулей". Есть много решений, и я не могу просто сказать - "вот этот способ лучше". У каждого есть свои достоинства и недостатки.

Comment: @БалунВладимир: А вы пользуйтесь кроме статей на Хабре ещё и здравым смыслом. Мало ли кто что на Хабре сказал.